# Are there a way to overwrite increment/decrement-handling for a input of type number?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

What i would like to do is manipulate the built-in html input buttons for increment and decrement of numbers. If there is a "vue-way" of doing this, that would of course be preferred.

First of all i'm working on a small vue-app that i've created for learning Vue, what i got now is a Vuex store which contains the state and methods for a shopping cart. I have bound the value **item.itemCount** seen in the image, to the value of the inputfield. But i would like the increment/decrement buttons to actually update the vuex-state in a proper way.

```
            <input
              class="slim"
              type="number"
              v-model.number="item.itemCount"
            />
```

I understand that i can just stop using a input-field, and create my own "count-view" + two buttons, but i'm curious if it's possible to do something like this.

UPDATE
Shoppingcart.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="sliding-panel">
    <span class="header">Shopping Cart</span>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
      </thead>

      <transition-group name="fade">
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>
            <input class="slim" type="number" v-model.number="item.itemCount" />
          </td>
          <td><button @click="removeProductFromCart(item)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
      </transition-group>

      <tr>
        Current sum:
        {{
          sum
        }}
        of
        {{
          count
        }}
        products.
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: mapState({
    items: (state) => state.cart.items,
    count: (state) => state.cart.count,
    sum: (state) => state.cart.sum,
  }),
  methods: mapActions("cart", ["removeProductFromCart"]),
};
</script>


<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Of course it is possible: if you want to customize the spinner buttons of an `input` field of type number, then it is better to hide the user-agent's default rendering of those spinner buttons and implement your own.

Comment: @Terry Okey, so how do one go about hiding only these buttons, and then implementing my own? And how would that differ from my last section 
"I understand that i can just stop using a input-field, and create my own "count-view" + two buttons, but i'm curious if it's possible to do something like this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need to "overwrite increment/decrement handling" in any way. You have the `<input>` so you need to handle all user inputs changing value - be it inc/dec buttons or user typing value directly...

Proper way of updating Vuex state is by using mutations. So even it's technically possible to bind `v-model` to some property of object stored in Vuex (as you do), it's not correct "Vuex way"

If there is only single value, you can use computed prop like this:

```js
computed: {
  myValue: {
    get() { return this.$store.state.myValue },
    set(value) { this.$store.commit('changemyvalue', value )} // "changemyvalue" is defined mutation in the store
  }
}
```

...and bind it to `input`

```html
<input type="number" v-model="myValue" />
```

But because you are working with array of values, it is more practical to skip `v-model` entirely - in the end `v-model` is just syntactic sugar for `:value="myValue" @input="myValue = $event.target.value"`

In this case

```html
<input type="number" :value="item.itemCount" min="1" @input="setItemCount({ id: item.id, count: $event.target.value})"/>
```

...where `setItemCount` is mutation created to change item count in the cart

Working example:

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Socks', itemCount: 2},
      { id: 2, name: 'Trousers', itemCount: 1}
    ]
  },  
  mutations: {
    setItemCount(state, { id, count }) {      
      const index = state.items.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
      if(index > -1) {
        const item = state.items[index]
        item.itemCount = count;
        console.log(`Changing count of item '${item.name}' to ${count}`)
      }
    }
  }
})
const app = new Vue({
  store,
  template: `
  <div>
    <span>Shopping Cart</span>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
      </thead>

      <transition-group name="fade">
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" :value="item.itemCount" min="1" @input="setItemCount({ id: item.id, count: $event.target.value})"/>
          </td>
          <td><button>Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
      </transition-group>
    </table>
  </div>
  `,
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState({
      items: (state) => state.items,
    })
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapMutations(['setItemCount'])
  }
})
app.$mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.5.1/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```

Comment: But you\re using Vue2 when OP tagged the question as Vue3...

Comment: @Terry Well, that's true. Do you see any Vue3 "only" code in his question?  I don't. The question is about "how to do it in Vue"...so I don't think it really matters my example is using Vue2